# Microsoft Word - always put Text Outline/Solid Line around pasted image

Tags: microsoft-word

When I paste images into Microsoft Word, I almost always want the solid line around them.
Is there a way to make this the default to avoid the four clicks of doing it manually [Right click - Format Picture, click the paint bucket, Click "line", then Click "Sold Line"].  I'm on Office 365 version.

Comment: What does "creating a box" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short web search seems to suggest setting [default](https://word.tips.net/T000671_Default_Picture_Settings.html) image [formatting](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/change-format-picture-defaults-in-word-2016/429ee741-8a4c-4f10-a24b-be1e261ee366) options is not supported. The suggestion I found is to record and use a macro to reduce the repetitive clicking.

However, if you only need a border around your image, I think you can handle this with a custom [Style](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-or-create-new-styles-d38d6e47-f6fc-48eb-a607-1eb120dec563) that you apply to all images.

With below steps you can set-up this style and re-use it throughout the document. It's a bit elaborate at first, but after setting this up it can be re-used easily. Additionally, it opens up the possibility to edit the border style of all images by simply editing the style once.

1. On the *Home* tab of the ribbon click on the drop down arrow of the Styles panel:
   [image]
2. Click *Create a Style* and give it a name
3. Right click on the style and modify the newly created style, make sure it is based on the "Normal" style:
   [image]
4. In the lower left click on *Format*:
   [image]
5. Select *Border...* and configure the desired border type and width, e.g.:
   [image]
6. Now, using the format menu from step 4, select *Paragraph...* and set the spacing as below:
   [image]
7. Lastly open the *Frame...* option and set the *Text wrapping* to *None*:
   [image]

After that style is set-up, this is how it looks in action:

[image]